# show uploaded images in dropzonejs in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm working on a Laravel project and I use Dropzone for products gallery.
everything is ok but I want to preload uploaded images from disk.

Here is my code:

```js
var mockFile = {
    name: "1573222244401photo_2019-11-06_10-35-41.jpg",
    size: 12345
};
dropzone.options.addedfile.call(dropzone, mockFile);
dropzone.options.thumbnail.call(dropzone, mockFile, "/images/product-galleries/1");
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addedfile' of undefined

Comment: Based on the code  you've shown here, I'd guess `dropzone.options` is undefined.

Comment: If `dropzone` is defined as the HTML element that dropzone is attached to than to access the actual dropzone instance you would need to do `dropzone.dropzone.options.addedFile.call(dropzone.dropzone, mockFile)`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you listed and the error message I would guess you are trying to call this function directly on the HTML element, not on the dropzone instance attached to it. If you are doing something like this

```
let dropzone = document.querySelecter('#dropzone-element')
```

Then to access the dropzone instance you would need to reference it as

```
dropzone.dropzone
```

Making your function calll

```
dropzone.dropzone.options.addedFile.call(dropzone.dropzone, mockFile)
```

To avoid this, just set `dropzone` equal to the actual dropzone instance like so

```
let dropzone = document.querySelector('#dropzone-element').dropzone
```